# Age of Design Patterns

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

When did these design patterns originate? Balking, Builder, Delegation, Facade, Memento. I have looked for days across the net, so if someone points me to a simple google search I may shoot myself. The real question I have is only which is the oldest and which is the youngest, so the specific dates for each are not important.

I have already found that the Balking pattern originated in 2002.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All but the Balking pattern are all GoF (Gang of Four) Patterns that were released in a single book.

[Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633612)

Comment: That's when they were *written down*, not when they originated. I'm pretty sure that the Delegation pattern is as old as programming itself. Actually, it is as old as *society* itself, or at least as old as *government*, which would be something like 5000 years?

Comment: perfect response, short sweet and to the point. I am fairly sure all i need is when they were first written.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I think you have to differentiate between delegation as a concept and delegation as a design pattern. Many software design patterns are based on some real-world concept, but looking for the origin of that concept probably won't add much to a conversation about software design. The GoF book usually cites frameworks that use the a given pattern, so it is indeed a good resource for looking into the history of a particular pattern.

Comment: @Caleb I agree, but the scope of the discussion was more towards when the design patterns, with regards to OOP, were more or less named. You could also trace the memento pattern(undo) back to the mid 70s at PARC.

Answer (score 10):

Patterns originated as an architectural concept by Christopher Alexander (1977/79). See [history section of the article about Design Patterns in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29#History).